# Deleting noisy data from a plot (manually) and export the best remaining data

Tags: image-processing, image, dataset, time-series, signal-processing

I have the following temperature time-series. As you can see it contains very very noisy points in some periods (Fig.A). I tried to approach the best data(the black one in the center) based on the idea mentioned here: [How to remove outliers from data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/81121/how-to-remove-outliers-from-data?rq=1) but I got weak time-series as demonstrated in the pink dots (Fig.c).

Therefore, what come finally to my mind is to manually delete the unwanted signals and then export the desired signal data and interpolate the missing data by tracking the deleted time steps. But I need help to do this, or if there is very powerful approach to eliminate the unwanted signals might be a solution (mathematical or image processing by Mathematcia). Thanks in advanced.[image]

data:https://drive.google.com/file/d/12I7HYE2cjEFUJF3zQIgeCx8O_Xqtviaa/view

P.S. I do not have any duplicate in my data i.e. each time step has only one value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Introduction

It seems to me that this question should be answered using more "traditional" time series methods than the already provided interesting solutions (with graphs and image processing.)

The workflow shown below is something considered during the design of the [QRMon](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2018/08/01/a-monad-for-quantile-regression-workflows/) package and it is very similar to the data cleaning done in ["Cleaning away data points which are enveloped within a function"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/189190/34008).

### The "traditional" time series procedure

1. Summarize the data
2. Do a (Quantile Regression) fit.
3. Pick points close to the fitted curve.

   - Using an appropriate threshold.
4. Plot the picked points.
5. If satisfactory results stop, else use the picked points as new data and goto to 1.

### Get the data

Actually the other answers did not discuss how the data is obtained. I downloaded the data from the provided link and had to pre-process it a bit.

```
data = Import["~/Downloads/MSE-q188361.txt", "Data"];

Tally[Length /@ data]
(* {{5, 1704}, {4, 34}} *)

data = Select[data, Length[#] == 5 &];
data = data[[All, 1 ;; 4]];
data = Select[data, VectorQ[#, NumberQ] &];
Dimensions[data]
(* {1703, 4} *)
```

### Workflow code

The implementation below uses the package [QRMon](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2018/08/01/a-monad-for-quantile-regression-workflows/):

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/master/MonadicProgramming/MonadicQuantileRegression.m"]
```

and `Fold`. Only two interations are needed, but I did experiment with different regression fits (algorithms, function bases parameters, and algorithm options) and different point picking thresholds.

The data is quite skewed, so the built-in function `Fit` does not work that well. The Quantile Regression algorithm is somewhat slow, but the whole computation should finish within 15 seconds.

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 cleanData =
   Fold[
    First[Values[
       QRMonUnit[#1]⟹
        QRMonEcho[Style[Row[{"Iteration parameters:\n{number of knots, quantile, pick threshold}=", #2}], Bold, Purple, FontSize -> 16]]⟹
        QRMonEchoDataSummary⟹
        QRMonQuantileRegression[#2[[1]], #2[[2]], Method -> {LinearProgramming, Method -> "InteriorPoint", Tolerance -> 10^(-3)}]⟹
        QRMonSetRegressionFunctionsPlotOptions[{PlotStyle -> Red}]⟹
        QRMonPlot[ImageSize -> Large, PlotLabel -> Style["Data and fit", Bold, 16]]⟹
        QRMonPickPathPoints[#2[[3]]]⟹
        QRMonEchoFunctionValue[ListPlot[#, ImageSize -> Large, PlotLabel -> Style["Picked points", Bold, 16], PlotTheme -> "Detailed"] & /@ # &]⟹
        QRMonTakeValue
       ]] &, 
    Join @@ data, {{16, 0.3, 0.1}, {30, 0.5, 0.025} (*,{24, 0.5, 0.01}*)}];
]
```

[image]

[image]

The final result is given to the variable `cleanData`:

```
Short[cleanData]
(* {{2, 5.3698}, {4, 5.3698} <<4563>> {6809, 4.813}, {6811, 4.813}) *)
```

Answer (score 24):

One simple way of "filtering" your data is to treat the points as a graph, and search for the shortest path from left to right:

```
xScale = 10.; 
xy = Transpose[{N[Range[Length[data]]]*(xScale/Length[data]), data}]; 

start = {-xScale, Mean[data]}; 
finish = {2*xScale, Mean[data]}; 
graph = NearestNeighborGraph[Join[{start}, xy, {finish}], 25]; 
graph = SetProperty[graph, 
   EdgeWeight -> 
    Apply[SquaredEuclideanDistance, EdgeList[graph], {1}]];
```

Now we have graph with all your points, plus two extra points "start" and "finish" far left and far right of the point set.

[image]

Every point is connected to it's 25 closest neighbors, and I'm using `SquaredEuclideanDistance` as edge weights -  that way, long edges are penalized, and the shortest path should contain all "inlier" points.

Here's the shortest path from start to finish:

```
path = FindShortestPath[graph, start, finish][[2 ;; -2]];
ListLinePlot[path, PlotRange -> MinMax[data], 
 Prolog -> {Gray, Point[xy]}, PlotStyle -> Red, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

---

## ADD:

I was asked what the `xScale` parameter means. Basically, it defines the cost of "skipping" a point of data, in relation to going "up and down" in y direction. So for smaller values of `xScale`, to cost of skipping a point is low, and a lot of points are skipped. If we increase `xScale`, more points get selected:

[image]

Comment: Very cool approach, nice...

Comment: @Niki Estner, Wonderful sir, I realized that the orjinal data length has been dramatically decreased decrease from 6919 to 2592!

Comment: Excuse me sir, I found that changing the value of the xScale = 10.; has a significant effect on the accuracy of the red line :)

Comment: @M.Basel: Yes, of course. By changing the x scale, you can basically adjust the cost of "detours" up and down. What would be the point of a filter with no adjustable parameters?

Comment: I am afraid if I could not understand your question very well so do you refer to y-axis?

Comment: How is the value of `data` obtained/derived?

Comment: @AntonAntonov: I downloaded the data file and used `ToExpression /@ Import[filename, "Lines"]`, IIRC. Normally, I include the `Import` line, but I couldn't import from Google drive directly.

Answer (score 9):

Here's an alternate approach that takes the data into an image that you can edit in a Paint program, and then back into data. Presumes you have "insider knowledge" about the data set that allows you to identify and exclude bad data.

Assuming the data is in `dat`, plot it

```
 ListPlot[dat]
```

[image]

Convert to an image, using a sparse array as an intermediary:

```
mindat = dat // Min
normdat = (dat - mindat)/((dat - mindat) // Max);
discretizer = 5000; (* discretizes the vertical axis, you pick the value to choose resolution *)
datsparse = Floor[normdat * discretizer] + 1;
sparsedata = Transpose[{datsparse, Range[Length[datsparse]]}];
rules = Map[# -> 1 &, sparsedata];
spa = SparseArray[rules]
MatrixPlot[spa, ColorFunction -> "Monochrome"]
```

[image]

From sparse array to image

```
immf = MaxFilter[Image[spa, "Bit"], 2]
Export["C:\\immf.tiff", immf]
```

Note: the `MaxFilter[ ]` command will result in multiple values for the same time step. Can delete if you want. Also note the image is inverted. Taken care of on the `Import[ ]`.

[image]

Edit it in your favorite paint program and import, reversing the math

```
immfmod = Import["C:\\immfmod.tiff"] // Binarize
```

[image]

Grab the data and renormalize. First the data...

```
imd = immfmod // ImageData
```

Get the location of positions where they have a value of '1', doing a little manipulating to get the X and Y axes correct, and transpose so we can scale the Y axis in the next step.

```
postrans = Transpose[Sort[Map[Reverse, Position[imd, 1]]]];
```

Reset the Y axis back to the original space

```
postrans[[2]] = (postrans[[2]] - 1)/discretizer ((dat - mindat) // Max) + mindat;
pos = postrans // Transpose;
```

Take a look

[image]

The data has repeated points for the same X-axis values. If you don't like that, get rid of the `MaxFilter[ ]` command, as I just used it to make the image easier to see.

Comment: Y, Wonderful sir, your approach resulted in larger number of elements, thus accepted range was data was 70%. 
The main challenge in this approach is to do perform continuous manual correction between export and import  but efficient. 
I do appreciate your contrbution!

Comment: Y, Dear sir, The removed outliers were 30% approximately. Alternatively, Mr. Niki's approach, gave greater percentage of outliers 57% approximately. 
The main difficulty is to treat outliers by paint (export, treat, import) for huge amount of data. 
Therefore, when treating the image by paint it is not essential to delete all outliers because I introduced (MedianFilter) to (pos[[All,2]]). Thanks all for supporting