# Extract data (digitise) from graph with various line formats

Tags: image-processing, data-acquisition

I am attempting to extract the data points from the graph below:

[image]

-axis titles and axis lines are removed for digitising simplicity-

I have tried using a range of graph digtisers (i.e. datathief, getdata, dcsdigitiser) but none of them are able to capture the data effectively without manual data points.

Is there a technique that accounts for solid, dashed and dotted lines and is able to distinguish from lines that are close together?

Using getdata, I managed to get this result:

[image]

However, there are not an equal number of points per line so data processing is difficult to account for this issue.

Comment: Fit each line to get *functions*, then sample each function with an equal number of points.

Comment: This is somewhat related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/188361/deleting-noisy-data-from-a-plot-manually-and-export-the-best-remaining-data/188370#188370

Comment: I know a solution for a pixel image of different curves of  unknown colors...