# Cleaning away data points which are enveloped within a function

Tags: data, filtering

I have some data taken in an experiment which I want to fit and analyse. But before I start fitting function, I want to clean points away in a robust but elegant way.

I first provide some sample data (apologies, the data before had the trailing digits hidden so when copying from M, it turned all the $y$-values constant, this is now fixed):

```
SampleData = {{43.10530996322632`, 2.9610372883599`*^7}, {86.2056188583374`, 
  2.9610373000033`*^7}, {129.31993007659912`, 
  2.9610373037403`*^7}, {172.42124128341675`, 
  2.9610373115104`*^7}, {215.53155136108398`, 
  2.9610373218762`*^7}, {258.6408619880676`, 
  2.9610373315972`*^7}, {301.7471733093262`, 
  2.9610373389542`*^7}, {344.8574833869934`, 
  2.9610373468751`*^7}, {387.9627933502197`, 
  2.9610373547716`*^7}, {431.06610345840454`, 
  2.9610373593744`*^7}, {474.1744132041931`, 
  2.9610373624969`*^7}, {517.2807245254517`, 
  2.9610373656209`*^7}, {560.388035774231`, 
  2.9610373672456`*^7}, {603.4873456954956`, 
  2.9610373687505`*^7}, {646.5896544456482`, 
  2.9610373718757`*^7}, {689.6949653625488`, 
  2.9610373718734`*^7}, {732.8042755126953`, 
  2.9610373718761`*^7}, {775.9205865859985`, 
  2.961037377287`*^7}, {819.0348963737488`, 
  2.9610373843758`*^7}, {862.1362056732178`, 
  2.9610373875002`*^7}, {905.2375154495239`, 
  2.9610373906252`*^7}, {948.3458256721497`, 
  2.9610373906256`*^7}, {991.4481363296509`, 
  2.9610373888359`*^7}, {1034.556447505951`, 
  2.9610373894297`*^7}, {1077.656756401062`, 
  2.9610373111623`*^7}, {1120.7750673294067`, 
  2.9610373944853`*^7}, {1163.8853783607483`, 
  2.9610373930747`*^7}, {1206.9916882514954`, 
  2.9610373937476`*^7}, {1250.1079993247986`, 
  2.9610373968739`*^7}, {1293.2153091430664`, 
  2.9610373999998`*^7}, {1336.3306202888489`, 
  2.9610374047823`*^7}, {1379.4399313926697`, 
  2.9610374078782`*^7}, {1465.656551361084`, 2.9610374093756`*^7}}
```

If I plot this data with `Show[ListPlot[SampleData], Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotRange -> {All, {Min[SampleData[[1 ;;, 2]]], 
    Max[SampleData[[1 ;;, 2]]]}}]` then we see:
[image]

Circled in red, we can see a point which doesn't fit the trend and I want to clean it away. Just for additional information the trend is described by 
$y(t) = a (1 - b e^{t / \tau})$.

Because the point is within the bounds of the function, I'm struggling to think of an appropriate method to clean such points away. When the bad points are above or below the maximum and minimum values (when sitting on the function I referenced) it's easy I can just select all points within a threshold. I could use the point-to-point jitter to clean but if I have to subsequent bad points near each other this also won't help, and again for points within the function envelope there is no way to distinguish them

I have hundreds of this sets to clean and fit, so a robust approach to cleaning data would be best -- if anyone has any ideas I'd be very grateful

Comment: Just out of curiousity, is there a known reason why these outliers exist? If you've taken hundreds of datasets and these outliers exist in all of them, is it possible that they're hinting at some kind of exciting phenomenon? Or is there a known quirk of the equipment being used that causes such substantial outliers?

Comment: @MassDefect A fair question. The data is acquired from FFT spectra as a single peak (the $y$ values) where the peak value is taken from a live peak fit on the acquisition software...the acquisition fit is a bit dumb so occasionally grabs a random noise peak. TL;DR version experimental limitation.

Comment: In your data, why your `y` values are the same?

Comment: Have you seen this?  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/188361/deleting-noisy-data-from-a-plot-manually-and-export-the-best-remaining-data

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci Eugh! I copied directly from M, trailing digits have been lost...one moment...AND very very nice link -- I will Have a good look at this!

Comment: What about the following: Perform the fit and look at the fit residuals. Identify the largest one and its x-coordinate and remove that one from the original dataset. If there are multiple outliers you could do this multiple times or define a maximum allowed value for the fit residuals and remove all points exceeding this value.
Would that do it?

Comment: Hi all, sorry about the bad data. I have corrected this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Update with the new, corrected data

*(For more details see the section with my first answer below...)*

With the new, corrected data (`SampleData`) in order to get good results I had to change the interpolation order and use special visualization with `Show` (as it is done in the question).

```
cleanData =
  QRMonUnit[SampleData]⟹
   QRMonQuantileRegression[6, 0.5, InterpolationOrder -> 2, Method -> {LinearProgramming, Method -> "InteriorPoint", Tolerance -> 10^(-3)}]⟹
   QRMonFit[8]⟹
   QRMonPlot["Echo" -> False]⟹
   QRMonEchoFunctionValue[Show[#, PlotRange -> {All, MinMax[SampleData[[All, 2]]]}] &]⟹
   QRMonErrorPlots["RelativeErrors" -> False, PlotRange -> All]⟹
   QRMonPickPathPoints[0.12]⟹
   QRMonTakeValue;
```

[image]

```
cleanData = cleanData[0.5];

Show[#, PlotRange -> {All, MinMax[SampleData[[All, 2]]]}] &@
 ListPlot[{SampleData, cleanData}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{PointSize[0.03], Pink}, Blue}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"data", "clean data"}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]
```

[image]

Also, note the difference of the magnitudes of the fit errors for the two datasets.

### First answer

Import the [QRMon package](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2018/08/01/a-monad-for-quantile-regression-workflows/):

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/\
MathematicaForPrediction/master/MonadicProgramming/MonadicQuantileRegression.m"]
```

Assign data (the data in the question has constant y-values):

```
data =
{{1387.5, 2.665*^7}, {1302.5, 2.635*^7}, {1222.5, 2.455*^7}, {1182.5, 2.385*^7}, 
 {1142.5, 2.315*^7}, {1097.5, 2.305*^7}, {852.5, 2.245*^7}, {897.5, 2.245*^7}, 
 {977.5, 2.225*^7}, {937.5, 2.205*^7}, {812.5, 2.175*^7}, {732.5, 1.955*^7}, 
 {652.5, 1.835*^7}, {692.5, 1.835*^7}, {567.5, 1.765*^7}, {527.5, 1.725*^7}, 
 {447.5, 1.625*^7}, {362.5, 1.455*^7}, {322.5, 1.275*^7}, {282.5, 1.095*^7}, 
 {242.5, 9.35*^6}, {202.5, 7.15*^6}, {157.5, 4.85*^6}, 
 {1017.9003407155026, 4.79701873935264*^6}, {77.5, 1.55*^6}};
```

Apply Quantile Regression, find and plot the fit errors, pick points close to fitted curve by using an appropriate threshold.

```
cleanData =
  QRMonUnit[data]y⟹
   QRMonQuantileRegression[12, 0.5, Method -> {LinearProgramming, Method -> "InteriorPoint", Tolerance -> 10^(-3)}]⟹
   QRMonPloty⟹
   QRMonErrorPlots["RelativeErrors" -> False]⟹
   QRMonPickPathPoints[10^6]⟹
   QRMonTakeValue;
```

[image]

Obtain the clean data from the monad application result and plot it together with the original data. (The outlier point is not in the clean data.)

```
cleanData = First[Values[cleanData]];

ListPlot[{data, cleanData}, PlotStyle -> {{PointSize[0.03], Pink}, Blue}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"data", "clean data"}, PlotRange -> All, PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]
```

[image]

Comment: That's basically what I suggested in my comment above. Out of curiosity: why not just use the built-in fit routines? Especially when the fit function is known as by @QuantumPenguin's question.

Comment: @gothicVI "why not just use the built-in fit routines?" -- They not work that well with this data/case. Quantile Regression with B-splines gives better results without fiddling too much with function models and parameters.

Comment: @gothicVI See my update that shows a fit using `Fit` with Chebyshev polynomials basis.