# Remove periodic data variation from experimental data

Tags: list-manipulation

I am a new user of Mathematica (ver. 9.0) and I kindly ask your help for some data analysis.
I have a list of measurement (Voltage) acquired at a constant frequency. This signal is interrupted periodically by a characteristic drop, which is intrinsic in the measurement method (see example below). The time zero is set at the middle of the first "drop".
[image]

Every drop is constitued by several datapoints, i.e., is not a single measurement (second image). 
I would like to exclude the drops from the data to work on the real signal which is the one comprised between each fall in the intensity. 
Can you suggest an easy way to filter or delete this artificial signal variation?

Thanks a lot!
[image]

P.S.
I also provide a data sample, which you can download from this link:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0qspq669ksk7lai/Iamorph.txt?dl=0

Comment: Try `MedianFilter[myData, 100]`.

Comment: Can you provide sample data to play with? (Also just out of curiosity, this looks like drops from opening the cover on a fluorimeter to add reagents?)

Comment: Do you want to remove the drops AND smooth the data?  Or just remove the drops?   It looks like once the drops to zero are removed there still exist jumps from one level to the next.  Are those jumps to be smoothed or left alone?

Comment: @JimB i just want to remove the drops, the jumps have to be left alone, It is what I actually need to measure. Thanks!

Comment: OK.  Then you definitely don't want to use `MedianFilter`.  And to second @MelaGo 's suggestion:  providing some sample data would get you quicker and better answers.

Comment: @JimB  In fact, this is why MedianFilter does not work well in my case.Sure I can share the data, is it possible to load a file in the post, or should I send them privately?

Comment: @MelaGo That was a nice guess! Actually the data come from trying to do spectroscopy during 3D printing

Comment: Putting the data in DropBox (or something like that) or if you can fit it in the post would be best in that you'll get a lot more interest and more direct answers.  I would guess that 3 or 4 full "cycles" should probably be enough.  But the example should also include the "non-flat" instances.

Comment: @JimB Ok, done! I copied the Dropbox link of full file in the main body of the post. Hope it works. Let me know if I should change something. Thanks a lot in the meanwhile!!

Answer (score 2):

This approach is based on the standard deviation of a moving window. It doesn't require regular periodicity of the drops, but the standard deviation cutoff and moving-window size may need to be adjusted.

```
sdcutoff = .1;
movingwindow = 8;
```

```
mw := If[EvenQ[movingwindow], movingwindow, movingwindow + 1] ;
sd = Table[{data[[n, 1]], 
    StandardDeviation[
     data[[All, 2]][[n - mw/2 + 1 ;; n + mw/2]]]}, {n, mw/2, 
    Length[data] - mw/2}];
```

Plotting the standard deviation shows the spikes that coincide with the drops (and helps select an appropriate sdcutoff).

```
ListPlot[sd, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"Time [sec]", "Standard Deviation"}]
```

[image]

Only keep `data[[t,y]]` for which the standard deviation of the moving window centered at t is < sdcutoff:

```
dataculled = {};
Do[If[sd[[n - mw/2 + 1, 2]] < sdcutoff, 
   AppendTo[dataculled, data[[n]]]],
  {n, mw/2, Length[data] - mw/2}];

ListPlot[{data, dataculled}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}]
```

[image]

Here is another example of data with similar drops, but not at regular intervals (from a fluorescence anisotropy binding experiment):

```
ListPlot[data2, Joined -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, -.1}]
```

[image]

```
sdcutoff = .03;
movingwindow = 30;
sd2 = Table[{data2[[n, 1]], 
    StandardDeviation[
     data2[[All, 2]][[n - mw/2 + 1 ;; n + mw/2]]]}, {n, mw/2, 
    Length[data2] - mw/2}];
ListPlot[sd2, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
dataculled2 = {};
Do[If[sd2[[n - mw/2 + 1, 2]] < sdcutoff, 
   AppendTo[dataculled2, data2[[n]]]],
  {n, mw/2, Length[data2] - mw/2}];
ListPlot[{data2, dataculled2}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 This must be much more robust by not having to assume a specific periodicity.

Comment: @JimB The tradeoff is that you have to fool around with the sdcutoff and window size, and as you can see, there are still a few erroneous points included. There's probably a way to automate it more, maybe by iterating and looking at the variance of the sd's,.. but I would have to take more time to think about it.

Comment: I guess the approach is dictated by what one really knows about the process in addition to the data.  If it's the "drops" and the drops have some consistent shape (as opposed to a consistent periodicity), then that knowledge could be exploited.  In short, it requires more (subject matter) information than what the data contains.  And many times getting that kind of information is hard to extract from whoever is asking the question.

Comment: @JimB, true. I was motivated to think about a solution without periodicity, because I sometimes have similar-looking data, such as in the second example. In that case, the "drops" (which can also be spikes) are due to a person opening the lid on the fluorimeter to pipette something into the cuvette. So obviously the interval and duration of the artifacts can vary quite a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Let's define the scan-window from the periodicity of your data in the array `data`:

```
win=218;
```

Let's scan your data with such window width:

```
ress = {};
Do[
 dd = data[[window*i + 1 ;; window*(i + 1)]];
 mm = MinMax@dd[[60 ;; 120, 2]];
 delta = mm[[1]]/mm[[2]];
 ress = Join[ress, Cases[dd, s_List /; s[[2]] > delta*mm[[2]]]],
 {i, 0, Floor@(Length@data/window) - 1}]
```

The result looks like this:

```
ListPlot[{data, ress}]
```

[image]

There are some mistakes of selector possible but it can be adjusted by the right choice of window size. It should be a bit **bigger** than the period of your data. An additional parameter is `delta`. Playing with it, you can change the selection results too.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I will soon apply your solution! All the bests

Answer (score 1):

This method, too, relies on assuming a drop approximately every 218 points.  (Maybe something not dependent on assuming a constant cycle is needed.  If so, please indicate that in your question.)

```
(* Find the potential minimums approximately every 218 points and \
within 22 points of either side of the initial potential minimum *)
d = 22;
low = Flatten[
   Table[Select[data[[Range[Max[1, i - d], Min[Length[data], i + d]]]],
     #[[2]] == 
       Min[data[[Range[Max[1, i - d], Min[Length[data], i + d]], 
          2]]] &],
    {i, 1, Length[data], 218}], 1];

(* Get a list of indices d points to the left and d points to the \
right of each potential minimum *)
pos = Flatten[
  Position[data, #] & /@ low]; (* Position of potential minimums *)
indices = 
 DeleteDuplicates[
  Sort[Flatten[
    Table[Range[Max[1, pos[[i]] - d], Min[Length[data], pos[[i]] + d]],
     {i, Length[pos]}]]]];

(* Keep just the "good" data *)
goodData = Delete[data, Table[{indices[[i]]}, {i, Length[indices]}]];

(* Show results *)
Show[ListPlot[goodData], ListPlot[data[[indices]], PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image: Data]

Comment: Great!! Thanks a lot for your help, I will try to implement it ASAP! Bests

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

data = Import["Iamorph.txt", "Table"];

```
(* select elements for a max distance to nearest neighbor *)
neigbors[limit_] := 
 Select[data, EuclideanDistance[#, Nearest[data, #, 2][[2]]] < limit &]

towns = neigbors[.02];

ListPlot[{data, towns}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, Directive[PointSize[.005], Red]}]
```

[image]

```
(* eliminate the sprinklink of small values *)
bigTowns = Select[towns, #[[2]] > .1 &]; bigTowns // ListPlot
```

[image]

```
(* moving median eliminates most outliers *)
medians = MovingMedian[bigTowns, 5]; medians // ListPlot
```

[image]

```
(* find the towns *)
clusters = 
  FindClusters[medians, 11, DistanceFunction -> EuclideanDistance, 
   Method -> "Agglomerate"];
```

[image]

```
(* and plot the mean values for each *)
Mean /@ clusters // ListPlot
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Below I am reusing the approach / code from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/189471/34008).

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/master/MonadicProgramming/MonadicQuantileRegression.m"]

data = Import["~/Downloads/Iamorph.txt", "TSV"];

cleanData =
  Fold[Function[{data, pars},
    (QRMonUnit[data]⟹
       QRMonEcho[Style[pars, Purple, Bold]]⟹
       QRMonEchoDataSummary⟹
       QRMonQuantileRegression[pars["knots"], pars["fraction"]]⟹
       QRMonPlot⟹
       QRMonErrorPlots["RelativeErrors" -> False]⟹
       QRMonPickPathPoints[pars["threshold"]]⟹
       QRMonTakeValue)[pars["fraction"]]
    ], data, {<|"knots" -> 50, "fraction" -> 0.5, "threshold" -> 1|>, <|"knots" -> 50, "fraction" -> 0.5, "threshold" -> 0.3|>}];
```

[image]

[image]

```
ListPlot[cleanData, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]