# Methods to filter

Tags: filtering

Hi I have a set of data electrical signal measurement in the time domain, may I seek some suggested on how can I filter this set of data.

The measurement was done over a period of 43 sec, at 200Hz per second, giving us around 8600-n data points.

I have tried using the moving average methods but it affects the accuracy of the reading.

Due to the data length, I have shorted the first cycle out of the 8 cycles.

Appreciate some suggestion in this. Thank you.

```
data = {0.867513, 0.855728, 0.853856, 0.86728, 0.888611, 0.899992,
       0.897373, 0.89681, 0.89681, 0.897202, 0.898732, 0.903969, 0.906013,
       0.907322, 0.90649, 0.901583, 0.900273, 0.898964, 0.899221,0.900995,
       0.903467, 0.904776, 0.90381, 0.901681, 0.899564, 0.89697, 0.886495,
       0.887766, 0.888672, 0.82461, 0.696748, 0.707224, 0.708008,0.821446,
       0.908964, 0.898438, 0.898438, 0.898438, 0.899368,0.900065,0.900065, 0.900065, 0.898781, 0.898438, 0.899086, 0.901056, 0.90496, 0.906269, 
0.905572, 0.902893, 0.899698, 0.898487, 0.899796, 0.901105, 0.902414, 
0.902916, 0.901693, 0.901693, 0.900616, 0.900065, 0.899625, 0.898438, 
0.898438, 0.838317, 0.724668, 0.634766, 0.643342, 0.714051, 0.850312, 
0.904152, 0.905462, 0.905989, 0.902061, 0.900506, 0.899197, 0.898438, 
0.898206, 0.896896, 0.89681, 0.895905, 0.895183, 0.894914, 0.893604, 
0.894815, 0.896125, 0.897434, 0.898438, 0.898438, 0.898438, 0.899416, 
0.900065, 0.900065, 0.900041, 0.898732, 0.898438, 0.898438, 0.898438, 
0.898438, 0.898438, 0.898438, 0.899172, 0.900897, 0.90332, 0.90332, 
0.902232, 0.900152, 0.89889, 0.900065, 0.900065, 0.900065, 0.899258, 
0.898927, 0.900065, 0.900065, 0.900065, 0.899222, 0.898438, 0.898438, 
0.898438, 0.891245, 0.888672, 0.888672, 0.890382, 0.899548, 0.900065, 
0.900065, 0.899466, 0.898438, 0.898438, 0.898438, 0.857416, 0.828451, 
0.828451, 0.828451, 0.886041, 0.89214, 0.887044, 0.88669, 0.885742, 
0.897527, 0.899038, 0.898438, 0.898047, 0.897029, 0.900957, 0.901693, 
0.901693, 0.900838, 0.898438, 0.898438, 0.898438, 0.897655, 0.89681, 
0.89681, 0.89681, 0.897948, 0.898438, 0.898438, 0.898255, 0.896946, 
0.89681, 0.897666, 0.898975, 0.899846, 0.898536, 0.897227, 0.89681, 
0.894512, 0.890556, 0.891865, 0.891927, 0.895645, 0.897827, 0.89681, 
0.89681, 0.895526, 0.895183, 0.89583, 0.897469, 0.899617, 0.84855, 
0.836589, 0.837273, 0.852504, 0.901644, 0.900335, 0.900065, 0.900065, 
0.900468, 0.901608, 0.900299, 0.900065, 0.899308, 0.898878, 0.900187, 
0.901496, 0.902805, 0.90332, 0.902844, 0.901693, 0.901693, 0.900543, 
0.900065, 0.899039, 0.897005, 0.898314, 0.898438, 0.898438, 0.788473, 
0.573149, 0.574458, 0.578213, 0.759462, 0.90332, 0.902784, 0.900165, 
0.900065, 0.899124, 0.894076, 0.887045, 0.887045, 0.888341, 0.896497, 
0.901693, 0.901693, 0.901669, 0.90036, 0.900065, 0.898672, 0.897189, 
0.898498, 0.899807, 0.901117, 0.901693, 0.901278, 0.900065, 0.900065, 
0.900065, 0.900835, 0.901693, 0.900357, 0.887262, 0.884292, 0.883789, 
0.888186, 0.898438, 0.898438, 0.898438, 0.898438, 0.898963, 0.900065, 
0.900065, 0.900065, 0.899185, 0.898438, 0.898438, 0.898438, 0.898438, 
0.898438, 0.898438, 0.898718, 0.900028, 0.898794, 0.898438, 0.897803, 
0.89681, 0.89681, 0.848403, 0.836589, 0.837261, 0.709447, 0.245804, 
0.247113, 0.248423, 0.533187, 0.901302, 0.899921, 0.897302, 0.89681, 
0.89681, 0.897665, 0.899956, 0.898647, 0.898438, 0.897656, 0.897274, 
0.898584, 0.899893, 0.901202, 0.902511, 0.90282, 0.90151, 0.900201, 
0.900065, 0.900065, 0.900065, 0.899846, 0.898537, 0.898438, 0.898438, 
0.903603, 0.913342, 0.914651, 0.914714, 0.907283, 0.901082, 0.894217, 
0.868028, 0.864946, 0.864258, 0.877204, 0.897139, 0.898438, 0.898438, 
0.866368, 0.799159, 0.73405, 0.735574, 0.777475, 0.856776, 0.89681, 
0.89681, 0.896895, 0.898204, 0.898438, 0.899195, 0.895673, 0.883789, 
0.883789, 0.882677, 0.889308, 0.89681, 0.896968, 0.898277, 0.899587, 
0.900065, 0.900065, 0.90026, 0.901569, 0.902878, 0.902453, 0.901693, 
0.901231, 0.898612, 0.898438, 0.898438, 0.899024, 0.900065, 0.900065, 
0.898807, 0.898438, 0.901551, 0.907185, 0.909804, 0.909831, 0.905921, 
0.902002, 0.868337, 0.748675, 0.747366, 0.748085, 0.812733, 0.898438, 
0.898378, 0.897069, 0.898912, 0.900065, 0.899651, 0.898534, 0.899844, 
0.900065, 0.900065, 0.899163, 0.89681, 0.89681, 0.897935, 0.898438, 
0.898438, 0.898438, 0.898438, 0.898438, 0.898438, 0.898963, 0.899859, 
0.898549, 0.898438, 0.896679, 0.895744, 0.878332, 0.778816, 0.774347, 
0.77474, 0.820188, 0.898438, 0.898438, 0.898438, 0.899391, 0.900065, 
0.899749, 0.898439, 0.863128, 0.854492, 0.851807, 0.857165, 0.890265, 
0.888956, 0.893804, 0.897518, 0.898828, 0.900065, 0.900065, 0.89794, 
0.896066, 0.895183, 0.895291, 0.896601, 0.89681, 0.897592, 0.897974, 
0.896955, 0.898265, 0.892756, 0.891118, 0.891927, 0.892836, 0.899383, 
0.900065, 0.900065, 0.899529, 0.898656, 0.899966, 0.900065, 0.900957, 
0.901119, 0.900065, 0.900065, 0.898819, 0.898438, 0.898438, 0.898438, 
0.898438, 0.898438, 0.899403, 0.900712, 0.901693, 0.901693, 0.901693,   0.900691, 0.901432, 0.902955, 0.90174, 0.903049, 0.901244, 0.900065,
0.899261, 0.89681, 0.89681, 0.89681, 0.898324, 0.900065, 0.900065, 
0.900065, 0.787784, 0.734884, 0.734525, 0.751234, 0.880867, 0.897958, 
        0.897608, 0.897322, 0.898438, 0.898438, 0.897253, 0.895943, 0.895183, 
        0.895413, 0.896723, 0.898032, 0.898438, 0.897853, 0.896276, 0.893657, 
        0.892296, 0.891927, 0.893172, 0.895487, 0.896796, 0.8994, 0.900065, 
        0.900065, 0.899725, 0.898416, 0.897106, 0.89681, 0.89681, 0.897188, 
        0.898438, 0.898438, 0.898438, 0.898438, 0.898438, 0.898534, 0.899843, 
        0.900065, 0.900065, 0.899615, 0.898438, 0.898438, 0.898438, 0.898438, 
        0.898438, 0.898438, 0.898438, 0.898438, 0.898438, 0.898438, 0.898438, 
        0.898438, 0.898438, 0.882617, 0.869141, 0.869141, 0.869141, 0.892583, 
        0.900065, 0.900663, 0.901413, 0.900104, 0.900065, 0.899113, 0.899072, 
        0.900065, 0.900065, 0.900065, 0.899076, 0.898438, 0.898438, 0.898472, 
        0.899782, 0.885705, 0.877986, 0.878906, 0.879902, 0.898234, 0.90063, 
        0.899321, 0.898864, 0.900173, 0.901482, 0.901693, 0.900912, 0.899603, 
        0.898438, 0.898438, 0.898438, 0.89762, 0.89731, 0.898438, 0.898438, 
        0.898438, 0.898438, 0.898438, 0.898656, 0.899965, 0.898856, 0.886855, 
        0.877279, 0.877279, 0.877279, 0.878525, 0.83345, 0.799763, 0.803986, 
        0.818389, 0.880247, 0.895846, 0.895829, 0.897138, 0.898438, 0.898438, 
        0.899439, 0.904845, 0.911458, 0.911458, 0.911458, 0.904194, 0.900785, 
        0.901693, 0.901693, 0.901693, 0.900618, 0.899309, 0.898876, 0.900065, 
        0.900065, 0.847842, 0.821982, 0.820787, 0.8293, 0.890843, 0.900733, 
        0.900863, 0.900065, 0.899872, 0.898563, 0.898438, 0.898438, 0.898438, 
        0.898208, 0.896899, 0.898031, 0.898438, 0.899023, 0.899799, 0.89849, 
        0.899696, 0.900065, 0.899444, 0.898741, 0.900051, 0.898771, 0.90039, 
        0.901034, 0.901085, 0.90497, 0.906279, 0.908602, 0.911221, 0.91497, 
        0.921458, 0.926696, 0.931933, 0.935708, 0.93874, 0.942764, 0.948002, 
        0.953239, 0.957709, 0.962087, 0.966533, 0.963914, 0.969158, 0.974095, 
        0.980944, 0.991717, 0.995645, 0.999574, 1.00434, 1.0101, 1.01563, 
        1.01563, 1.02041, 1.02565, 1.03369, 1.04257, 1.03864, 1.04211, 
        1.04604, 1.07444, 1.12091, 1.12614, 1.13011, 1.10263, 1.08362, 
        1.04556, 0.879259, 0.884133, 0.890359, 0.984042, 1.11434, 1.11823, 
        1.12085, 1.12347, 1.1275, 1.13274, 1.13805, 1.1446, 1.14796, 1.15206, 
        1.15688, 1.14299, 0.929556, 0.898478, 0.903187, 0.988842, 1.19658, 
        1.1992, 1.20181, 1.19871, 1.10387, 0.89898, 0.902908, 0.906836, 
        1.06871, 1.21526, 1.21788, 1.2205, 1.22433, 1.22648, 1.22893, 
        1.23286, 1.23679, 1.24196, 1.25276, 1.26037, 1.26256, 1.26779, 
        1.26021, 1.26007, 1.26139, 1.26205, 1.26468, 1.2686, 1.27253, 
        1.27578, 1.2784, 1.28097, 1.28228, 1.28463, 1.28725, 1.28986, 1.2924, 1.29371, 1.29502, 1.29708, 1.2997, 1.30232, 1.30494, 1.30756, 
        1.31097, 1.31395, 1.31526, 1.31657, 1.31673, 1.31756, 1.31989, 
        1.32382, 1.32775, 1.33168, 1.33214, 1.33138, 1.33115, 1.32984, 
        1.32975, 1.32885, 1.32813, 1.32813, 1.32813, 1.32813, 1.32813, 
        1.32813, 1.32782, 1.32651, 1.3265, 1.32552, 1.33145, 1.34081, 
        1.33952, 1.33952, 1.18257, 1.08585, 1.08361, 1.09083, 1.282, 1.32104, 
        1.32088, 1.31875, 1.3151, 1.3151, 1.3151, 1.31434, 1.31348, 1.31348, 
        1.31348, 1.3146, 1.3143, 1.31348, 1.31331, 1.312, 1.31069, 1.30938, 
        1.30807, 1.30676, 1.30545, 1.30534, 1.30622, 1.30753, 1.30859, 
        1.30859, 1.30736, 1.30697, 1.30637, 1.30534, 1.30534, 1.30407, 
        1.30276, 1.30208, 1.30208, 1.30208, 1.30208, 1.3011, 1.30046, 
        1.30081, 1.30205, 1.30074, 1.29943, 1.29742, 1.29596, 1.2972, 1.2972, 
        1.2972, 1.29794, 1.29883, 1.29893, 1.30024, 1.30485, 1.30697, 1.3065, 
        1.30462, 1.29807, 1.2972, 1.29802, 1.29833, 1.2972, 1.2972, 1.29603, 
        1.30154, 1.30643, 1.30534, 1.30534, 1.29688, 1.29395, 1.29395, 
        1.29395, 1.29395, 1.30639, 1.31022, 1.31022, 1.30703, 1.29263, 
        1.29232, 1.29232, 1.29296, 1.29493, 1.29878, 1.29224, 1.23069, 
        1.19099, 1.15652, 1.04923, 1.12648, 1.14776, 1.07528, 0.974614, 
        0.958249, 0.951701, 1.16089, 1.27935, 1.29025, 1.2811, 1.19337, 
        1.18001, 1.18081, 1.21338, 1.29085, 1.29215, 1.29232, 1.29315, 
        1.29343, 1.29213, 1.29082, 1.28951, 1.2882, 1.28744, 1.28744, 
        1.28744, 1.28988, 1.29159, 1.2929, 1.29501, 1.30025, 1.30046, 
        1.29952, 1.29573, 1.29039, 1.28908, 1.28906, 1.28809, 1.28678, 
        1.28547, 1.28345, 1.23762, 1.22823, 1.22884, 1.24199, 1.28575, 
        1.28444, 1.28418, 1.28418, 1.28377, 1.28265, 1.28396, 1.28418, 
        1.28495, 1.28581, 1.28581, 1.28581, 1.28581, 1.285, 1.28467, 1.28598, 
        1.28728, 1.19473, 0.999198, 0.850715, 0.865947, 0.970701, 1.20456, 
        1.28668, 1.28744, 1.28695, 1.28433, 1.28172, 1.09539, 0.939797, 
        0.921502, 0.922811, 1.18043, 1.27132, 1.28924, 1.29689, 1.29558, 
        1.29427, 1.28506, 1.27997, 1.28128, 1.28259, 1.28389, 1.28418, 
        1.28418, 1.28379, 1.28255, 1.28255, 1.28255, 1.28329, 1.2863, 
        1.29232, 1.29232, 1.29122, 1.28601, 1.28046, 1.2793, 1.2793, 1.2793, 
        1.28011, 1.28142, 1.28255, 1.28255, 1.27553, 1.27193, 1.27116, 
        1.27246, 1.28031, 1.28334, 1.23349, 1.19198, 1.19253, 1.18991, 
        1.26194, 1.28233, 1.28032, 1.27872, 1.2761, 1.27604, 1.277, 1.27896, 
        1.28092, 1.28092, 1.28092, 1.28092, 1.27343, 1.19659, 0.965124, 
        0.963815, 0.974939, 1.11354, 1.28052, 1.2793, 1.2793, 1.27822, 
        1.27767, 1.27767, 1.27767, 1.27767, 1.27878, 1.2793, 1.2793, 1.27914, 
        1.27783, 1.27767, 1.27767, 1.27767, 1.27844, 1.28367, 1.28418, 
        1.28504, 1.28362, 1.27907, 1.27776, 1.27767, 1.27406, 1.27116, 
        1.27116, 1.27116, 1.27618, 1.27861, 1.2793, 1.2793, 1.2793, 1.2793, 
        1.26565, 1.25651, 1.25617, 1.25517, 1.2735, 1.19372, 1.14327, 
        1.14421, 1.14893, 1.25761, 1.2793, 1.2793, 1.2793, 1.2792, 1.27789, 1.27658, 1.27527, 1.27441, 1.27441, 1.27441, 1.27441, 1.27522, 
 1.27653, 1.27784, 1.27915, 1.27814, 1.27767, 1.27715, 1.27604, 
        1.27604, 1.27485, 1.27529, 1.2766, 1.27767, 1.27767, 1.03012, 
        0.949608, 0.949489, 1.00593, 1.26781, 1.27604, 1.27414, 1.2513, 
        1.21745, 1.21745, 1.21745, 1.251, 1.27279, 1.27279, 1.27279, 1.27279, 
        1.27279, 1.27349, 1.27441, 1.27435, 1.27304, 1.27173, 1.27042, 
        1.26995, 1.27137, 1.27399, 1.27551, 1.28383, 1.29278, 1.29409, 
        1.2954, 1.2831, 1.26381, 1.08195, 0.700049, 0.701358, 0.717881, 
        1.01143, 1.24769, 1.1786, 1.07123, 1.06283, 1.10549, 1.18774, 
        1.27441, 1.27441, 1.28063, 1.28255, 1.28194, 1.2523, 1.12267, 
        0.815074, 0.734346, 0.795566, 0.964906, 1.27603, 1.27341, 1.27179, 
        1.27048, 1.26917, 1.26786, 1.26655, 1.26731, 1.26862, 1.26993, 
        1.2578, 1.04174, 0.975799, 0.961914, 1.03339, 1.23178, 1.26452, 
        1.26953, 1.27032, 1.27163, 1.27279, 1.27279, 1.23842, 1.2223, 1.2207, 
        1.22624, 1.26422, 1.26909, 1.26953, 1.26953, 1.26976, 1.27107, 
        1.26994, 1.27043, 1.27116, 1.27142, 1.27273, 1.27279, 1.27091, 
        1.21132, 1.11684, 1.11815, 1.11946, 1.21137, 1.27147, 1.26953, 
        1.26953, 1.26953, 1.26953, 1.26953, 1.26953, 1.26953, 1.26953, 
        1.27058, 1.27116, 1.27116, 1.27116, 1.27116, 1.20936, 1.17839, 
        1.17749, 1.18265, 1.2586, 1.27626, 1.2801, 1.28044, 1.2783, 1.27044, 
        1.27069, 1.27116, 1.27064, 1.26933, 1.26802, 1.2679, 1.2679, 1.2679, 
        1.2679, 1.2679, 1.26913, 1.26953, 1.26894, 1.2679, 1.2679, 1.26664, 
        1.26628, 1.26565, 1.26465, 1.26465, 1.26726, 1.2679, 1.26857, 
        1.26918, 1.2679, 1.2679, 1.2679, 1.2679, 1.26829, 1.26946, 1.26815, 
        1.26684, 1.26628, 1.26585, 1.26465, 1.26465, 1.26465, 1.2662, 1.2679, 
        1.2679, 1.2679, 1.2679, 1.26872, 1.26903, 1.2679, 1.2679, 1.26673, 
        1.26628, 1.26574, 1.26465, 1.26465, 1.26465, 1.26554, 1.26628, 
        1.26628, 1.26628, 1.26503, 1.26557, 1.26628, 1.26628, 1.26628, 1.265, 
        1.26561, 1.26692, 1.2679, 1.26783, 1.25474, 1.25163, 1.25163, 
        1.25525, 1.26786, 1.26655, 1.26628, 1.26556, 1.26465, 1.26465, 
        1.26465, 1.26465, 1.26465, 1.26465, 1.26477, 1.26608, 1.26628, 
        1.26707, 1.26696, 1.26465, 1.26465, 1.2635, 1.26385, 1.26414, 
        1.26302, 1.26302, 1.26302, 1.26388, 1.26519, 1.26605, 1.26474, 
        1.26587, 1.26538, 1.26465, 1.26465, 1.26465, 1.26465, 1.26559, 
        1.26628, 1.26628, 1.26628, 1.26628, 1.21954, 1.18815, 1.18815, 
        1.18905, 1.25059, 1.26566, 1.26628, 1.26628, 1.26622, 1.26491, 
        1.26465, 1.27048, 1.27726, 1.27604, 1.27604, 1.26737, 1.26302, 
        1.26302, 1.26302, 1.26302, 1.26414, 1.26465, 1.26465, 1.26465, 
        1.26465, 1.26349, 1.26386, 1.26465, 1.26485, 1.26616, 1.26389, 
        1.26215, 1.22851, 1.14288, 1.01979, 1.0136, 1.07056, 1.17194, 
        1.27116, 1.27116, 1.26736, 1.26533, 1.26465, 1.26496, 1.26627, 
        1.26497, 1.26563, 1.26561, 1.265, 1.26628, 1.26628, 1.26628, 1.19163, 
       1.09336, 1.09212, 1.09212, 1.20332, 1.26228, 1.26139, 1.2615, 
        1.26281, 1.26412, 1.26387, 1.26302, 1.26302, 1.26302, 1.26415, 
        1.26465, 1.26961, 1.2811, 1.28241, 1.28138, 1.27156, 1.26249, 
        1.26161, 1.26292, 1.26423, 1.26376, 1.26359, 1.26465, 1.26465, 
        1.26465, 1.26372, 1.26242, 1.25304, 1.21507, 1.21419, 1.21515, 
        1.23446, 1.2627, 1.26139, 1.26008, 1.25977, 1.26045, 1.26176, 
        1.26302, 1.26302, 1.26199, 1.19478, 1.11281, 1.1215, 1.12281, 
        1.22266, 1.26914, 1.26259, 1.26128, 1.25997, 1.25977, 1.25977, 
        1.26024, 1.26139, 1.26139, 1.26139, 1.26057, 1.26027, 1.26158, 
        1.26289, 1.26302, 1.2613, 1.25977, 1.25977, 1.25977, 1.2622, 1.26212, 
        1.26139, 1.26139, 1.26139, 1.26265, 1.26396, 1.26403, 1.26272, 
        1.26141, 1.2601, 1.25977, 1.23619, 1.20151, 1.20282, 1.20413, 
        1.24078, 1.26233, 1.26139, 1.26139, 1.26139, 1.20384, 1.17115, 
        1.16984, 1.17358, 1.24429, 1.25651, 1.25728, 1.25859, 1.25977, 
        1.25977, 1.26089, 1.26139, 1.26139, 1.25842, 1.23485, 1.23325, 
        1.23456, 1.24419, 1.26302, 1.26302, 1.26302, 1.26215, 1.26084, 
        1.25929, 1.25667, 1.25651, 1.25469, 1.25266, 1.25108, 1.24846, 
        1.24837, 1.24648, 1.24386, 1.24124, 1.23862, 1.2373, 1.04882, 
        0.922772, 0.917271, 0.920462, 1.16663, 1.2207, 1.2193, 1.21668, 
        1.21406, 1.21144, 1.20882, 1.2062, 1.20401, 1.20166, 1.18725, 
        1.18271, 1.17853, 1.17788, 1.18447, 1.18055, 1.17775, 1.17513, 
        1.17251, 1.17025, 1.17025, 1.16674, 1.16366, 1.16105, 1.15864, 
        1.15733, 1.15602, 1.15382, 1.15178, 1.14996, 1.14604, 1.15825, 
        1.14733, 1.13667, 1.13338, 1.11374, 1.1299, 1.13252, 1.1299, 1.12728, 
        1.12466, 1.12073, 1.11879, 1.11681, 1.11419, 1.11174, 1.11436, 
        1.11491, 1.11348, 1.10927, 1.10157, 1.09633, 1.09002, 1.08649, 
        1.08474, 1.0827, 1.08663, 1.08502, 1.0832, 1.08094, 1.07702, 1.07309, 
        1.06916, 1.06441, 1.06018, 1.05737, 1.05345, 1.05188, 1.05057, 
        1.04926, 1.0475, 1.04357, 1.03964, 1.03661, 1.03458, 1.03327, 
        1.03196, 1.02814, 1.02515, 1.02253, 1.02021, 1.0189, 1.01759, 
        1.01433, 1.01106, 1.00811, 1.00421, 1.0029, 1.00059, 0.997967, 
        0.994975, 0.990992, 0.985755, 0.981563, 0.977635, 0.974526, 0.973125, 
        0.970506, 0.967887, 0.964504, 0.960575, 0.956775, 0.954157, 0.953776, 
        0.952975, 0.948768, 0.940426, 0.937807, 0.936344, 0.940062, 0.943491, 
    0.942383, 0.942383, 0.94119, 0.939881, 0.938571, 0.9375, 0.9375, 
        0.9375, 0.936589, 0.935279, 0.922702, 0.867707, 0.87095, 0.871448, 
        0.895326, 0.932687, 0.92614, 0.926107, 0.927091, 0.927734, 0.927386, 
        0.926107, 0.926107, 0.925086, 0.924479, 0.92371, 0.921224, 0.921224, 
        0.921224, 0.923444, 0.926107, 0.926107, 0.926107, 0.925012, 0.925256, 
        0.926107, 0.925826, 0.923208, 0.920589, 0.919597, 0.920092, 0.921401, 
        0.922711, 0.922852, 0.922002, 0.924946, 0.932404, 0.931094, 0.932194, 
       0.868787, 0.815998, 0.816807, 0.815498, 0.896122, 0.920301, 0.919597, 
        0.919023, 0.916404, 0.917619, 0.917969, 0.917969, 0.917645, 0.916341, 
        0.916341, 0.917338, 0.917969, 0.855286, 0.634808, 0.636117, 0.63536, 
        0.759197, 0.917969, 0.917654, 0.912416, 0.911459, 0.910707, 0.911566, 
        0.916341, 0.916341, 0.916341, 0.91713, 0.917969, 0.917817, 0.916507, 
        0.916341, 0.916341, 0.916341, 0.916341, 0.916341, 0.916341, 0.916341, 
        0.916341};
```

[image]

Comment: I cannot see a question in this post.

Comment: What kind of filtering are you looking for? Having cleaner looking data? Removing the outliers and picking up the outliers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting noisy data from a plot (manually) and export the best remaining data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/188361/deleting-noisy-data-from-a-plot-manually-and-export-the-best-remaining-data)

Comment: Try a median filter: ListPlot[{data, MedianFilter[data, 15]}] looks pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

Let's use [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/188361/deleting-noisy-data-from-a-plot-manually-and-export-the-best-remaining-data)  method. Play with parameters if it is necessary.

```
 xScale = 2.;
    xy = Transpose[{N[Range[Length[data]]]*(xScale/Length[data]), data}];

    start = {-xScale, Mean[data]};
    finish = {2*xScale, Mean[data]};
    graph = NearestNeighborGraph[Join[{start}, xy, {finish}], 10];
    graph = SetProperty[graph, 
       EdgeWeight -> 
        Apply[SquaredEuclideanDistance, EdgeList[graph], {1}]];

    path = FindShortestPath[graph, start, finish][[2 ;; -2]];
    ListLinePlot[path, PlotRange -> MinMax[data], 
     Prolog -> {Gray, Point[xy]}, PlotStyle -> Red, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]