# How to visualize and interactively correct time series data

Tags: data, filtering, visualization, interactive

I am looking for an efficient method to visualize measured time series data with about 100.000 data points per year, such that eye-catching data points may interactively be tagged as suspicious, e.g. using the mouse button. The problem I have in other software environments is that the process of updating the data point status (suspicous / OK) takes much too long time, at least, if several time series are displayed at once (which is necessary). Is there any way in Mathematica to handle these large amounts of data in an efficient way?

Comment: If you want to have it _fast_ and _in Mathematica_, then don't make it interactive. Instead, make a plot, guess what the charactistics of the outliers are, develop appropriate filter criteria, and filter them out (e.g., by using `Pick`) in conjunction with these filters. This might sound very abstract but in view of the lack of an appropriate example dataset, that's all I can do for you at the moment.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/188361/764) or [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/81121/how-to-remove-outliers-from-data?noredirect=1&lq=1) and related/linked posts there?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could reduce the number of points you need to plot trivially, but would have to see what the data actually looks like in order to suggest something.

Comment: I will load up my data in a minute - the problem is that the data need to be checked as such and in combination with other quantities, since it is not that trivial to detect the causes for erroneous measurements without this. The three columns with water content should at least be displayed at the same time and also the meteorological variables.

Comment: The problem is that several time series are necessary to decide wheather a data point needs to be delete or not. I have put and example dataset on https://www.hidrive.strato.com/lnk/EdEOHzUi  . At least the 3 water content time series and the meteorological variables are necessary to be displayed at once.